# Qt - synchronizing threads not working - threads stop but really don't, and sometimes do when they shouldn't

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have four threads. Two play and analyze videos using OpenCV, one saves data and acts as a middleman between videos and GUI, one is GUI.

My idea was this - video thread does things, sends the frame to the middleman, and stops itself. If it's the first frame in the pair sent, middleman does nothing but set a flag - otherFrame. In theory, since video one's stopped, now the other video sends a frame, the flag of the other frame is True, so middleman emits both frames to the onPassFramesGui, where the frames are placed in QLabels, and then both threads are resumed. And then it loops.

That's the theory and I have no doubt it's wrong. In reality, the video with lower resolution will sooner than later overtake the other one. Like it's never paused.

In video threads, while they do slightly different things, this is the common part of the code:

```
for(nrKlatkiOne=1; nrKlatkiOne<maxFramesOne; nrKlatkiOne++) {
(....)
    emit sendFrameOne(imageOne, nrKlatkiOne);
    pauseThread();
    pause.lock(); //mutex
    if(threadPausedOne==true){
        pausedCond.wait(&pause); //QWaitCondition
    }
    pause.unlock();
}
```

and

```
void VideoOne::pauseThread() { //in VideoTwo "One"s are replaced with "Two"s, so the variables are exclusive to their threads
    if(threadPausedOne==false){
        pause.lock();
        threadPausedOne=true;
        pause.unlock();
     }
}

void VideoOne::resumeThread() {
    if(threadPausedOne==true){
        pause.lock();
        threadPausedOne=false;
        pause.unlock();
        pausedCond.wakeAll();
    }
}
```

in the middleman thread, this is the slot that receives the signal (there's a similar signal for VideoTwo):

```
void Analiza::onSendFrameOne(QImage frameOneImage, int frameNoOne) {  

//videoOne->pauseThread();        
one = frameOneImage;    
frOne = frameNoOne;  

if(otherFrameTwo == true && videoTwoLoaded == true){  
    emit passFramesGui(one, two, frOne, frTwo);  
    pauseMutex.lock();     
    otherFrameOne = false;    
    otherFrameTwo = false;
    pauseMutex.unlock();
} else if(videoTwoLoaded == false) {   
    emit passFramesGui(one, two, frOne, frTwo);   //to GUI
}
if(otherFrameTwo == false){     
    pauseMutex.lock();
    otherFrameOne = true;                  
    pauseMutex.unlock();
    qDebug() << "otherFrameOne = true";
}
}
```

and the last, but not least, please bear with me, this function sets the images in the GUI

```
void MainWindow::onPassFramesGui(QImage one, QImage two, int frameNoOne, int frameNoTwo){ 

if(videoOneLoaded==true) {          
    <converting image>
    <keeping aspect ratio>
    (setting stuff)
}

if(videoTwoLoaded==true) { 
    <same stuff here>
}

if(videoOneLoaded == true) { 
    videoOne->resumeThread();
}

if(videoTwoLoaded == true) { 
    videoTwo->resumeThread();  
}
}
```

I've put QDebug messages to get a rough idea what's going in. Sooner or later this happens:

```
(....)
otherFrameOne == true && videoOneLoaded == true //frames emitted from onSendFramesTwo
otherFrameTwo = true //onSendFramesTwo received the frame, waits
otherFrameTwo == true && videoTwoLoaded == true //onSendrameOne sent the frames
otherFrameOne = true //onSendFrameOne received a frame
otherFrameOne = true //onSendFrameOne received another frame? But it's stopped...
```

I'm pretty sure stopping threads work. If I remove resumeThread() from either, the program will just stop. It will send frame 1, 2 -> gui, then 1 and it'll just stop.

Another case is when there's just one video loaded, instead of two. The video thread will just stop stop at random at not resume. I have a signal that qDebugs a message, and after the video stops, it won't do anything (can be resumed when I change tabs - which causes the `threadPausedOne`/`Two` to be set to true and then to false.

The code compiles without any errors or warnings.

What is the correct way to do this? It's my first time doing this kind of thing.

Oh, a bonus question. Is it better to have two separate slightly different objects, or one with 60% more code and just create multiple instances?

Comment: why don't you use another condition variable for the VideoOne pause\resume mechanism? `threadPausedOne` is accessed by several threads without mutual exclusion (if(...)). If you want a pausing mechanism, why don't you simply use signals and slots?

Comment: @UmNyobe what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Don't have time to analyze your code right now, but you check threadPausedOne before you lock the pause mutex, so I'd say, that is your error.

Comment: Apparently you don't need the boolean `threadPausedOne`. You can use the condition variable `pausedCond` without condition.

Comment: @UmNyobe how would that look in code? to make the condition go to sleep I have to call something. Every example I've seen used a bool. PS: each threadPausedNumber are used only by one thread. Hm. I'll try signals and slots. There's something that hasn't occured to me.

Comment: You have at least 4 variables (`threadPauseNumber` and  `otherFrameNumber`) in your code, for which you protect the write access with a mutex but not the read access. If reads and writes are all happening in the same thread, then you don't need a mutex at all, if they happen in different threads, then you need to protect both the read and write access otherwise you get UB. Also it would be helpfull, to see a little bit more of your code, like how do you create those threads and where is e.g. `videoOneLoaded` set? And have you shown all locations, where `otherFrameOne` is used?

Comment: @MikeMB the `videoOneLoaded` is set true when the `videoOne` object is created. This happens once for each video, when the URL is loaded from GUI via `QFileDialog`. videoOne is a `QObject` that is moved into a thread it creates. And yes, those are all the places these values have been used, except for that one `videoLoaded`

Comment: Do you have one  `pausedCond` variable per video thread or a single one for both?

Comment: @MikeMB they have their own conds. VideoOne and VideoTwo don't share anything with each other. However, for various reasons, they have to work in exact parallel. If I can't do it, it won't be a disaster, but will make conducting the experiment more difficult and inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

You have overcomplicated it, introducing a lot of flags and synchronization objects. I suggest that you use two `QSemaphore` per video thread. I will name them `allowWork` and `hasFrame`.

The video thread will work as follows:

```
// Wait until middleman allows work (when it has handled a pair of frames)
allowWork.acquire(1);

// Do frame processing here
// ...

// Tell middleman one frame is ready
hasFrame.release(1);
```

The middleman thread will work as follows:

```
// Wait until both video threads have a frame
video1.hasFrame.acquire(1);
video2.hasFrame.acquire(1);

// Handle a pair of frames here
// ...

// Tell video threads to make another pair of frames
video1.allowWork.release(1);
video2.allowWork.release(1);
```

In startup code, you will initialize `allowWork` to 1, and `hasFrame` to 0.

With this approach, it will also be easy to add a buffer for frames from video1 and video2 (for example both video threads work until they have 16 frames ready each, while middleman still handles once a pair is available), this way you're likely to get better thread utilization.

Comment: I still need flags for loading videos, as there may be only one loaded, not necesserily two. But thank you for that answer - it's certainly a new PoV at this question. I'll try ASAP

Comment: got a chance to apply this solution... the GUI becomes unresponsive, app freezes and resumes every dozen or two frames, and the video desynch anyway... I must've done something wrong

Comment: Probably. Your GUI thread does not have any locks according to my design, so it shouldn't freeze.

Comment: neither does mine. GUI thread doesn't do anything that isn't related to directly manipulating one button or another label.

Comment: I can only suggest that you debug carefully. What you describe shouldn't happen in my design, and without code, it's hard to guess. I believe you accidentally call some method from a locked thread or something like that. Anyway, it's best if you take your time to debug it.

Comment: will do. But tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You must lock your mutex whenever you use the shared variables, for writting (as you do), but also for reading

Example:

```
void VideoOne::pauseThread() { //in VideoTwo "One"s are replaced with "Two"s, so the variables are exclusive to their threads
    pause.lock(); // lock here
    if(threadPausedOne==false){
        // pause.lock(); // not here!
        threadPausedOne=true;
        // pause.unlock(); // not here!
    }
    pause.lock(); // unlock here
}

void VideoOne::resumeThread() {
    pause.lock(); // lock here
    if(threadPausedOne==true){
        // pause.lock(); // not here!
        threadPausedOne=false;
        // pause.unlock(); // not here!
        pausedCond.wakeAll();
    }
    pause.lock(); // unlock here
}
```

For `resumeThread()`, if wakeAll must be called when `pause` is not locked, just do this. That's a trick you may have to use in other places to prevent dead-locks...

```
void VideoOne::resumeThread() {
    bool needWakeAll = false;
    pause.lock(); // lock here
    if(threadPausedOne==true){
        threadPausedOne=false;
        needWakeAll=true;
    }
    pause.lock(); // unlock here
    if ( needWakeAll )
        pausedCond.wakeAll();
}
```

`onSendFrameOne` most likely has to be reworked the same way...

Comment: Unfortunetly this hasn't changed anything. Videos still randomly stop (once every few attempts), and videos get ahead of each other.

Comment: Did you do the changes for all concurrent functions/methods?

Comment: yes, of course. I listened to other comments as well, and now videos stop constantly. I think I'm going to rewrite this whole section.

Answer (score 0):

You think you locked the mutex and no other is accessible to it, but both threads look they change the boolean value and try lock the mutex. Isn't it?

The boolean value is set, but it's accessed while the mutex not locked in a moment.

Look over Wikipedia article [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). It will help.

Comment: Doesn't this apply if both my threads used the same variable? But both my threads are based off a bit different objects, and each has it's own unique variable set

Comment: Try making it volatile and double checked, for your shared flags only.